# prestodb raises IllegalArgumentException: base is empty for one mongodb collection

Tags: presto

I just discovered that there's a single collection on my MongoDB that I can't query with prestodb (server and CLI on version 0.157).

All other collections can be queried normaly, but this one collection can't be queried directly or joined with anything else. It is not the biggest nor the most complex of the collections, but apparently presto is having trouble with types.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: base is empty
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.type.TypeSignature.checkArgument(TypeSignature.java:370)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.type.TypeSignature.<init>(TypeSignature.java:48)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.type.TypeSignature.parseTypeSignature(TypeSignature.java:101)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.type.TypeSignature.parseRowTypeSignature(TypeSignature.java:199)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.type.TypeSignature.parseTypeSignature(TypeSignature.java:104)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.type.TypeSignature.parseTypeSignature(TypeSignature.java:94)
    at com.facebook.presto.mongodb.MongoSession.buildColumnHandle(MongoSession.java:199)
    at com.facebook.presto.mongodb.MongoSession.loadTableSchema(MongoSession.java:185)
    at com.facebook.presto.mongodb.MongoSession.access$000(MongoSession.java:76)
    at com.facebook.presto.mongodb.MongoSession$1.load(MongoSession.java:128)
    at com.facebook.presto.mongodb.MongoSession$1.load(MongoSession.java:123)
    (...) very long stack trace
```

I've searched a few issues related to collection naming, but this one follows the same conventions (it actually has no underscores, some of the others do and it works).

What are the most likely causes for this? Maybe an inconsistent schema? (I have clues that a certain field in MongoDB has date and sometimes integer, but that would require a lot of digging to confirm)

Comment: I'd file an issue with the Presto project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @miniway, I've figured out that Presto failed to infer the complete schema for a few embedded documents.

By running

```
db.getCollection("_schema").findOne({"table" : "tableName"})
```

I've noticed a few mappings like `row()`, which meant that Presto failed to map it. The particular field was hard to map because it was a generic python dictionary inserted through `pymongo`, which means no fixed schema.

The "solution" was to simply define that part of the schema manually, using a varchar to hold the dictionary.